# Sorting Specific node in nested XML

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I am trying to sort specific nodes in a nested XML. I can sort them fine but the output does not contain the other XML fields that are supposed to be copied.

Input:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<PerPerson>
  <PerPerson>
    <personalInfoNav>
      <PerPersonal>
        <lastName></lastName>
        <firstName></firstName>
        <personIdExternal></personIdExternal>
        <startDate></startDate>
      </PerPersonal>
    </personalInfoNav>
    <personIdExternal></personIdExternal>
    <employmentNav>
      <EmpEmployment>
        <personIdExternal></personIdExternal>
        <assignmentClass></assignmentClass>
        <compInfoNav/>
        <jobInfoNav>
          <EmpJob>
            <employeeClass></employeeClass>
            <seqNumber>2</seqNumber>
            <startDate>2020-06-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
          </EmpJob>
          <EmpJob>
            <employeeClass></employeeClass>
            <seqNumber>3</seqNumber>
            <startDate>2020-01-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
          </EmpJob>
          <EmpJob>
            <seqNumber>1</seqNumber>
            <startDate>2019-06-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
          </EmpJob>
        </jobInfoNav>
        <userId></userId>
      </EmpEmployment>
    </employmentNav>
  </PerPerson>
</PerPerson>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="PerPerson/PerPerson">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="employmentNav/EmpEmployment/jobInfoNav/EmpJob">
            <xsl:sort select="startDate" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="seqNumber" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I make sure that everything else is copied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="jobInfoNav">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="EmpJob">
        <xsl:sort select="startDate" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="seqNumber" order="descending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

For explanation, see: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#section-Processing-Model

Comment: Thank you for the link you provided